# WCF in IIS with ASP.NET compatibility mode on, HTTP request thread different than WCF service operation

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0

I've a WCF service hosted on IIS with ASP.NET compatibility mode.

The problem is I've checked the thread for the HTTP request, handled in the Global.asax, isn't the same as the one executing a service operation.

How can I make the service operations to be invoked in the same thread of HTTP request?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

*The underlying problem is I was using an HTTP module in order to make some objects available during a request, and when a response is going to be sent, these are disposed/released.*

*Since some of these objects are stored in thread static fields, there's no way of sharing them in the WCF service operation.*

*Maybe there's another way of doing so. For example, doing something before some WCF service operation is invoked, and after this has ended. I'll appreciate any suggestion.*

Comment: I don't think that you have any control over the thread affinity for service operation execution. What is the underlying issue that you are trying to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea to store anything in thread variables as there's no direct control on the way the runtime manages threads between ASP.NET pipeline and WCF host pipeline in IIS.

Is it possible that you use the `Items` container? In the ASP.NET compatibility mode the container will be available throughout the whole request pipeline. This way you can easily store/retrieve some data there and do not worry much about resource consumption as the container will be automatically destroyed at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was out for a day, in some hours I'll check it.

Comment: This is the right answer, because I can keep doing with HTTP module. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, I would strongly recommend moving the logic from your HTTPModule into code that is executed by the WCF service calls. We have common functionality and validation that is performed and provided for every service call and to support this, we require the developers to call a single, common method at the start of each service call.

This isn't quite as elegant as an HTTPModule solution due to the extra code, but by doing this we end up with a nicely contained unit of work for each service call that has well-known setup and teardown points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was out for a day, in some hours I'll check it.

Comment: Thank you again, it's just another approach, but as @Wiktor has pointed out in his answer, there's a workaround for my problem and it's working fine.